# Cannot set KDiff3 as merge/diff tool in GIT

Tags: git, kdiff3

Recently I have been trying to setup KDiff3 as mergetool. So I fetched the program, installed it and wanted to set it as GIT diff and merge tool.

In order to do that, I executed command:

```
git config --global merge.tool kdiff3
git config --global mergetool.kdiff3.path "C:/Program Files/KDiff3/bin/diff3.exe"
git config --global mergetool.kdiff3.trustExitCode false

git config --global diff.guitool kdiff3
git config --global difftool.kdiff3.path "C:/Program Files/KDiff3/bin/diff3.exe"
git config --global difftool.kdiff3.trustExitCode false
```

Which correctly set my config file to this:

```
[user]
    email = turek1992@o2.pl
    name = Michal Turczyn
[merge]
    tool = kdiff3
[mergetool "kdiff3"]
    path = C:/Program Files/KDiff3/bin/diff3.exe
    trustExitCode = false
[diff]
    guitool = kdiff3
[difftool "kdiff3"]
    path = C:/Program Files/KDiff3/bin/diff3.exe
    trustExitCode = false
```

...and now I caused conflicts in my branch, trying to open mergetool shows me only this:
[image]

And if I press `y`, file stays with GIT conflict marks anyway, if I press `n` it simply aborts merge.

And this happens no matter whehter I use

```
git mergetool --tool kdiff3
```

or

```
git mergetool
```

Note: I always worked with VS for these purposes and it worked just fine.

**The question**: how to make it work, so KDiff3 correctly picks up confilted files and lets me manage it, just as it should.

Comment: fwiw: kdiff3 has a standard config included with git, you shouldn't need to specify the `mergetool.kdiff3.*`  and `difftool.kdiff3.*` options

Comment: not clear from your question : does kdiff3 open at all ? with a 3-way merge view ?

Comment: @LeGEC Nothing happens. Of course, i can go to installation directory and open it, but I expected it to open by default after typing in console `git mergetool`

Comment: does it work if you remove your two `[mergetool "kdiff3"]` and `[difftool "kdiff3"]` sections ?

Comment: also: please update your question to make it clear that calling `git mergetool` doesn't open the editor (the terminal part that you show would be the same if kdiff3 had started)

Comment: @LeGEC it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are referring to `kdiff3.exe` executable. It is usually placed in main installation directory of KDiff.

In my case it was simply `C:/Program Files/KDiff3/diff3.exe`

So execute this instead (with corrected paths)

```
git config --global mergetool.kdiff3.path "C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe"
git config --global mergetool.kdiff3.trustExitCode false

git config --global diff.guitool kdiff3
git config --global difftool.kdiff3.path "C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe"
git config --global difftool.kdiff3.trustExitCode false
```